# Cannot use Mail.php from command line

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, cron, smtp

I have a php script that is going to be a cron job and it was working fine until I added the email script I have been using.

I have used the email script all over the site before but when I try and run the cron job using it from the command line it fails.

The mail script looks as followed

```
    <?php

require_once "Mail.php";

function sendMail($to, $from, $subject, $message) {

        $no_errors = true;

        $host = "ssl://smtp.server.com";
        $port = "465";
        $username1 = "username";
        $password = "password";

        $headers = array ('From' => 'myfromemail@myemail.com',
          'To' => $to,
          'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
          array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username1,
            'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {

            $no_errors = false;

            echo $mail->getMessage();

        } else {

            $no_errors = true;

         }

        return $no_errors;

        }

?>
```

If I comment out the include send_mail.php it works fine but doesn't send email.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure that, when the script is ran from `cron`, it has the proper working folder set, so it can load `mail.php`. Using the [`getcwd()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and [`chdir()`](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) functions are the two you need to use.

Usually, when ran from web browser (on an Apache server), the working directory is `/var/www`, but from `cron`, it is usually the root of the filesystem, `/`.

Answer (score 1):

When including external files, you need to be conscious of where the file is, and then where PHP will look for it. You can inspect where it will look with [get_include_path()](https://www.php.net/get_include_path) and set it with [set_include_path()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php). When you set a new one, you want to ADD (not replace) the directory where Mail.php is installed. Use `get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $yourPath` as the new value.

Answer (score 1):

The standard folder when you're running a cron is probably different to the folder in which this include is contained. Try this:

```
require_once realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/Mail.php' );
```

In the general case, you can add in `..` or folder structures as required - and it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

Try "locate Mail.php" from Command line, and then try full path of this script in your require_once

Also try to dump the response into a log file, when it's ran via cron:

[Cron Job Log - How to Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/cron-job-log-how-to-log)

Comment: Tried locate and nothing came back. Mail.php is from pear so im not sure why