# Running crontab with python

Tags: python, linux, cron

Python crontab script doesnt seem to work. When i run it manually,

```
python /home/ec2-user/code1.py
```

it works fine but when put into cron.txt file for the crontab, doesnt.

My crontab file is:

```
 @hourly python /home/ec2-user/code1.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

i also tried

```
0    *    *    *    * python /home/ec2-user/code1.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

But neither have much luck.

```
sudo crontab -l
@hourly python /home/ec2-user/code1.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Shows everything functional.
I tried [Crontab not running my python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-running-my-python-script) and couple others with not much luck either.

### EDIT:

With

```
PATH=/opt/python2.7/bin  
MAILTO=my@email
*/5 * * * * /home/ec2-user/code1.py
```

Email i get is:

```
 /bin/sh: /home/ec2-user/code1.py : No such file or directory
```

Yet I can open and edit the file no problem. I tried many different thing but it comes down to this: cron doesnt see the file.

Feels like I went through entire https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work
and still no luck

Comment: Check `cron` is actually running - it might not be for sufficiently but down VM images.

Comment: have you check your PYTHONPATH on .bashrc?

Comment: @AlperTokgöz how do i check with .bashrc? i check python version it is 2.7 and all my dependencies are for 2.7. I run the command as it is in bash no problem, its just when i add cron notation and put it into crontab it screws up

Comment: @DouglasLeeder i checked with sudo crontab -l, any other way i should check? I am not too proficient with PIDs so couldn't check that

Comment: @rodling if your code use another module of yours, it should be added in pythonpath in .bashrc. if you don't have idea about .bashrc problem is not interested with it. forget my comments. * you can add basic python code to your crontab, like print a string to file. it may help you to specify the problem.

Comment: Leave out the redirects to `/dev/null` and see what email you get: `cron` will email stdout/stderr to the owner (in this case root). Using the full path, `/usr/bin/python`, is generally a good idea in `crontab` entries, since you can't be sure what the `PATH` is.

Comment: @Emmet I added #!/opt/python2.7/bin at the top, thats where my 2.7 is located. Is that correct directory or should it remove bin?

Comment: @rodling: Aha! Your problem is, most likely, that `cron` can't find your `python` interpreter. The default path for `cron` is usually just `/usr/bin:/bin`, so one alternative is to add `PATH=/opt/python2.7/bin` to the top of your `crontab`. A better solution is probably that given by Thor, below, but the shebang line in the script must be the full path to the python interpreter, e.g. `#!/opt/python2.7/bin/python`, not just to the containing directory.

Comment: @Emmet with shebang line i still need to do `0    *    *    *    * python /home/ec2-user/code1.py >/dev/null 2>&1` with `python` or no?

Comment: @rodling: No, if your script contains the correct shebang line and is executable (e.g. chmod 755 code1.py), it can be invoked directly. There is no need to invoke the interpreter with the script's filename as an argument.

Comment: How are you telling that your script is working or not? Does it create a file? Because you are sending your output to `/dev/null`, as @Emmet mentioned, it won't give feedback like it will when you run it "manually". If it is truly silent, maybe give it some output just to debug. Also you can add MAILTO=your.address at the top of the `crontab` file to get error reports.

Comment: @rodling `ps aux | grep [c]ron` should show a running process if cron is enabled.

Comment: If the error message is correctly copy/pasted, you have somehow managed to put an extra literal space or other invisible character after `code1.py`. I don't understand how exactly this could happen, but make sure there is just a Unix newline at the end of that line in your crontab.

Comment: @beroe It updates DB which is very visible to me. I updated the post with email output

Comment: @tripleee i concluded that is most likely case, and i looked into that extensively. I edited the file with pressing enter in notepad, no luck. When i create new line in vi after the .py, it gives me bad minute error

Comment: Sounds like you need to remove the next line in vim as well then. And sounds like I'm on to something.

Comment: @tripleee in vim it doesnt seem to have a new line
`MAILTO=my@email
*/3 * * * * /opt/python2.7/bin/python /home/ec2-user/insider_data_pull.py
~`

Comment: how are you modifying the cron file? Which command are you using?

Comment: @LtWorf i initially did with notepad, than moved to vim

Comment: @roding, you should only edit the crontab with `crontab -e`, set `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables to crontol which editor is launched. (Since you started out with notepad, I take it you don't like vim.)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling i moved towards vim and -e already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Verify cron is running: `ps aux | grep [c]ron` should show a running cron process
2. Remove the redirects from the command so that cron emails you the output
3. Add a `MAILTO=<email address>` to your crontab, so that you get the email
4. Put the full path to python (`/opt/python2.7/bin/python`) instead of just `python` in the command
5. Add another command to crontab such as `echo FOOBAR` and verify that you get the email.
6. `ls -l /homeec2-user/code1.py` ? Should that be `/home/ec2-user/code1.py`
7. Only ever edit a user's crontab with `crontab -e` never from another platform, or by editing the file directly.
8. Run `crontab -l | cat -A` so that we can verify all the control characters are correct.

Comment: email works
Finally got a bug, it says 
`/bin/sh: /homeec2-user/code1.py`
`: No such file or directory`

Comment: @rodling Really `/home/ec2-user/code1.py` - looks like that's missing a `/` - `/home/ec2-user/code1.py`

Comment: that was just my mistake not in actual code. It has the correct `/` in the code

Comment: i did `ps` command you suggested. It seems to be running. I do youse full extension for python rather than just `python` and I created dummy crontab Foobar, and i get it on my email along with error codes for python one

Comment: i got 
`MAILTO=""^M$
*/3 * * * * /opt/python2.7/bin/python /home/ec2-user/code1.py^M$`

Comment: @roding.. it's those ^M$ that are the culprit. Start over; `crontab -r` and *follow step 7.* Like I commented on the question, you can set `EDITOR` to control which editor is launched. Notepad users tend to prefer `pico` over `vim`

Comment: @ChrisWesseling thanks! I rewrote the crontab from scratch with `crontab -e`  after `-r` and it now works!

Answer (score 1):

did you check the following points?

- is your script executable? `chmod 700 code1.py`
- the first line in your code should be, in most cases the python is installed at this place

  - `#!/usr/bin/python`

after that the crontab as follow should execute

```
0    *    *    *    * /home/ec2-user/code1.py >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I tried chmod and nothing happened
I added `#!/opt/python2.7/bin` at the top, thats where my 2.7 is located. Is that correct directory or should it remove bin?
Also in your crontab, the shebang removes which program to run it with so no need for `python` before the code directory?

Comment: @rodling: the shebang line doesn't go in the crontab, it goes in your script. The shebang “#!” must be the first two characters in the file (no space or blank lines before it) and the full path to the interpreter executable, not just the containing directory, must appear on the same line, e.g. `#! /opt/python2.7/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

If the error message is correctly copy/pasted, it seems to reveal that there is a problem with the crontab file. If you created it on a foreign platform, it might be best to start over with an empty file, this time creating it in a native editor.

As others have already pointed out, redirecting output and errors to `/dev/null` basically makes debugging impossible, so don't do that. If your program creates copiously verbose uninformative output, run it in a wrapper which filters out the trivial diagnostics, or, if it is your own program, rewrite it to run silently in normal operation.

Comment: crontab basically doesnt see the file. I ran `ps aux | grep [c]ron` and it seems to work. Program works 100% and the email simply says `/opt/python2.7/bin/python: can't open file '/home/ec2-user/code1.py': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "/usr/bin/python" instead of "python"?

ps ax | grep python
will give you the path you could use.

Answer (score 0):

try this command that should hopefully where your python is :

```
which python
```

very likely you will have something like

```
/usr/bin/python /home/ec2-user/code1.py
```