# Python-crontab module

Tags: python, linux, cron, centos7

I'm trying to use **Python-crontab** module over Linux OS (CentOS 7)

My config file is as follows:

```
{
  "ossConfigurationData": {  
    "work1": [
      {   
        "cronInterval": "0 0 0 1 1 ?",      
        "attribute": [
          {             
            "rules": [
                {
                    ......
                }
               ]               
            }
            ],
    "work2": [
      {   
        "cronInterval": "0 0 0 1 2 ?",      
        "attribute": [
          {             
            "rules": [
                {
                    ......
                }
               ]               
            },
            ]
      }
```

}

The file contain many work items. Each work item has it own cron expression. I want my Python script to be able to schedule each cron separately, set it in my OS & run it. When running, the purpose is running each work item separately according to it cron expression
I did step-by-step according to [this](https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/) tutorial. After many tests it's writing the cron, but I'm not sure it's what I need

Using this module, I can't create reference to the relevant work item. It's just adding a new line to the OS crontab with any execution I want to put there. I can't describe what I wish to run (i.e. - *work1* or *work2*)

Any suggestions?

10x in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running crontab with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513562/running-crontab-with-python)

Comment: @stovfl: That link you said is a duplicate is about running Python programs on a schedule configured in cron.  This question is about configuring cron using a Python program.

Comment: "Nothing works" is never an adequate problem description.  Show us the code you tried and tell us exactly what happened when you ran it.

Comment: ***"but nothing works"***: Whera are the differents between running a **Python Script** or **any executable**, the **Cron** setup is the same. [Edit] your Question and explain your **nothing works**.

Comment: According to the [GitLab repo](https://gitlab.com/doctormo/python-crontab/commits/master) and the [pypi sumary](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/), this module is still supported. And of course not, it is not limited to Ubuntu distro.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I've added information to  my question

Answer (score 0):

A common error is not using the cron.save() function after editing. Given the limited information in the question, this is the most likely answer.

Comment: Hi @Martin - I'm not using cron.save().
I'll try to be more clear - I have Json config file that contain many **work items**. Each work item has it own cron expression. I want my Python script to be able to schedule each cron separately, set it in my OS & run it, when the cron occur, with the content of the specific work item.

Comment: Hi Aviv, What you're describing isn't a problem in the `python-crontab` module, but some connection between the json and your crontab. I don't understand enough about your codebase to know why it's not working. It should and what you're asking for is reasonable. Alsa something isn't right.

Comment: Hi @Martin. I've updated my original question with code sample. Pls. take a look