# Running Python package console script with cron

Tags: python, cron

I have a [Python package](https://github.com/aarzee/airship) which provides a console executable `airship` which I would like to run on a regular basis using cron. However, when I add a line to my crontab that should do this, the script never executes. I have a way of telling when my script is being executed (my Steam status shows me as playing a specific game). This is the result of `crontab -l`:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/env airship
```

(The 2 is just for testing purposes, ideally it would be 15).

What is stopping this from happening?

Comment: is it installed on path?   if you run airship from an arbitrary folder, does it work?

Comment: I ran it from `/` and it worked fine. So yes, it's on `$PATH`.

Comment: Chances are it has permissions issues and cannot be run from system process as it doesn't have access to some resource. Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475694/how-to-specify-in-crontab-by-what-user-to-run-script

Comment: The crontab in question is not for the root user, so I don't think this is the problem. (I verified this with `sudo crontab -u aarzee -l`, my user is aarzee).

Comment: Have you tried something simple like checking if echo hello > file.txt executes?

Comment: I have now, and it does work. https://ghostbin.com/paste/rfdyu

Comment: Now, I'd suppose you should do the same with airship - pip the output to a file.

Comment: I've done this, but the file that is created is empty (it does exist though).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79710/discussion-between-carlos-liam-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-running-my-python-script) which helped me with the same problem.

It's possible that crontab doesn't locate python interpreter. So `which python` locates your python, for example `/usr/local/bin/python`

Locate your app `which airship` for example `/usr/local/bin/airship`

So crontab should be something like:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/airship
```

Maybe package has some other problems, check it with environment used by crontab: `env -i /bin/bash --noprofile --norc` and then run your script.