# Trouble running Python script CRON: Import Error: No Module Named Tweepy

Tags: python, unix, terminal, cron, tweepy

**Background:** I am following [Crontab not running my python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-running-my-python-script) in an attempt to debug and run my python script using CRON. Per SO suggestions, I tried `/usr/bin/python /Users/eer/Desktop/myscript.py` on the terminal.

**Problem:** However, I get a an error: `ImportError: No module named tweepy`. So, I tried to `pip install tweepy` and I get the following:`Requirement already satisfied: tweepy in /Users/eer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages` . So it seems I have tweepy but when I `/usr/bin/python /Users/eer/Desktop/myscript.py` it doesn't seem to read it. Suggestions?

Comment: What is the result of `which pip`?

Comment: `which pip` gives  `/Users/eer/anaconda/bin/pip`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `/usr/bin/python MyScript.py` command and your `pip` command are invoking two different python interpreters. Try either:

```
/Users/eer/anaconda/bin/python MyScript.py
```

or

```
/usr/bin/pip install tweepy
```

The former will invoke your personal Python interpreter, the one that already has `tweepy` installed. The latter will install `tweepy` for the system-wide Python.

You may need to invoke the latter option as root, for example, `sudo /usr/bin/pip install tweepy`.

Comment: I tried `sudo  /usr/bin/pip install tweepy` but i get `command not found`

Comment: I also tried `/Users/eer/anaconda/bin/python MyScript.py` and I get  `ERROR: unknown command MyScript.py`

Comment: 1) So you don't have pip installed in your system. If you want to use pip to install tweepy into the system Python, you'll have to install pip first. I'm not sure how to install it in OSX (which I assume you are using.) 2) Give the full path to the script, just like you tried in the question: `/Users/eer/anaconda/bin/python /Users/eer/Desktop/myscript.py`.

Comment: I still need to figure out how to install pip but `/Users/eer/anaconda/bin/python /Users/eer/Desktop/myscript.py` worked! thank you

Comment: @ER_18 - This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271319/how-do-i-install-pip-on-macos-or-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a basic uninstall and then reinstall:

```
pip uninstall tweepy
```

and then:

```
pip install tweepy
```

Comment: I tried and get an error `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

Comment: What OS are you running and what are your permissions on it?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux/Unix environment, cronjob usually runs with root privilege. You can check using the following command

```
ps -eF | grep cron
```

When installing tweepy, you might have installed as the normal user. Install tweepy as root and it should work.

```
sudo /usr/bin/pip3 install tweepy
```