# KeyError 'PATH' when running script from cron

Tags: python, cron

I have a Python script that works when run from the normal Terminal (and from any location) but fails when running from cron, throwing a `KeyError: 'PATH'` error.

A comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12534242/1167783) suggests that this is because cron runs with a different environment. When I switch using `env -i /bin/bash --noprofile --norc` as suggested, the `KeyError` is raised and appears to be from `os.environ["PATH"]` not being set, which I can confirm.

How do I set that, and to what? Can I make this permanent for cron?

**EDIT:** My question is very similar to some others, but different in that it threw a specific error from Python – I think keeping this question will help if anyone gets the same `KeyError`?

Comment: what causes the error exactly? Do you try to open a file that is supposed to be contained in the same folder as your script? If yes, you can get the path of your current script via `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` if that's of any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get CRON to call in the correct PATHs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388087/how-to-get-cron-to-call-in-the-correct-paths)

Comment: It's an installed library calling `os.environ["PATH]`. My libraries are all in my user's `bin` folder.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE – very similar, yeah didn't see that one in my searching. Doesn't come from the `KeyError` though, so maybe this specific situation is helpful to others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your environment variables, like `PATH` in your `/etc/crontab` file.

Eg.:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user   command
01 01 * * 1-5 root python /path/to/file.py
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369/1513933

Comment: Super helpful – is there a way to test this outside of a cron job? (ie directly from the Terminal instead of changing the times over and over?)

Comment: Yes, you can try `su - login`, where _login_ is the login of the cron. And then execute the Python code.

Comment: Hmm, how do I know the login of the cron? (Your solution worked, by the way!)