# Cronjobs not sending any e-mails

Tags: cron

I have some cronjobs written on several servers using CentOS7 in combination with Plesk 18.
When I check my cron log I see that the cronjobs are started.

Even when I manually start the scripts I want to use they work, but for some reason when the crontab does it, nothing is happening.

For instance some of the cronjobs I have are:

```
MAILTO=support@shoptrader.nl

0       0       *       *       *       sh /var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/remove_files.sh

0       6       *       *       *       sh /var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/security_htaccess/security_htaccess.sh

15      7       *       *       *       sh /var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/backup_personal_files.sh

30      9       *       *       *       sh /var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/find_hacks/find_hacks.sh
*/5     *       *       *       *       sh /var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/find_sql_injection/find_sql_injection.sh

15      0       *       *       *       sh /var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/backup_templates_data/backup_templates_data.sh

If I check my log I see something like: Jan 14 09:30:01 web14 CROND[4402]: (root) CMD (sh /var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/find_sql_injection/find_sql_injection.sh)
```

I've notified myself with e-mails and get this response

```
/var/www/vhosts/upgrade14.shoptrader.com/httpdocs/find_sql_injection/find_sql_injection.sh: line 12: php: command not found.
```

Which doesn't make sense, because PHP is working on the server.

Comment: include full path to `php` might help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-executing-a-python-script

Comment: Do you mean adding the path in the SH script itself?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I encounter that problem with my SH script too, some of my execute does not recognize my alias, (maybe only my command tools read some bash_alias file but the crontab process does not load it)

Comment: Hi @PhungDuyPhong how do I exactly write this? Something like php /path/to/php? Or is it just the path? I'm not really sure

Because right now, I have PHP /path/to/php and the path to which file it must run

Comment: `/path/to/php` is the correct way to go