# Python "print" function not working with crontab

Tags: python-3.x, linux, cron

I was trying to run some python script periodically in a linux-based OS, and after some quick research, I found that [crontab](https://linuxize.com/post/cron-jobs-every-5-10-15-minutes/) is a classic approach for this. I was a newbie to that command, so I made sure to keep in mind the common existing [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-executing-a-python-script) for it, and (cautiously) I decided to firstly go with a very simple python code, `myscript.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

print("If you see this, your periodic code ran OK!")
```

The *'cron table'* (`crontab -l`) file looked as follow, which was suppossed to run `myscript.py` every minute (I wanted to quick-test it):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/my_user_folder/Desktop/test/myscript.py
```

The seconds passed, the script reached its first elapsed minute... and nothing happened. To "*solve it*", I tried several things, but eerily (to me) I realized that most (if not all) tutorials and posts, used to store messages in *.txt* or similar files. I did something alike (after some hours, trials and no success), by modifying `myscript.py` to:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# NOTES:
# 1. This code is the 'final version' after several trials
# 2. Remember that I was aiming to automate anything, just
#    to get familiar with `crontab`; in this case, storing
#    the current time to some .txt file was enough.

import time

t = time.localtime()
current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

with open('/home/my_user_folder/Desktop/test/readme.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(current_time)
    f.write('\n')
```

...and **it worked**. I felt a bit silly, because I got to realize that my initial implementation (in regards of code, environmental settings, permissions, etc.) was indeed correct from the beginning, and yet *using the Python command `print` to 'test' recurrent tasks with `crontab` 'did not work'*...

**Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard output of a command executed from crontab is *not* sent to the standard output of your shell. (It wouldn't make much sense for it to do so; a cron job will continue to run after you've logged out.)

Typically `crontab` will (attempt to) email the output to you. This is configurable. `man 5 crontab` for more information.

Rather than modifying your Python script to redirect its own output, you can redirect the output in the crontab entry itself:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/my_user_folder/Desktop/test/myscript.py > output.txt
```

Comment: Hello Keith. Let me see if I understood: if I keep my original `myscript.py` (with only the "print" Python function), and I modify the cron table file the way you suggested, what I should see in `output.txt` is the original message ""If you see this, your periodic code ran OK!"", is that correct?

Comment: Hello again Keith. The answer to my previous question in the comment section is "YES". I tried "printing" a randomly generated character, which kept changing and being stored in "output.txt", every passing minute. Thank you, I will accept your post as answer.

Comment: Hi Keith, when you say that crontab will attempt to email the output, does this mean that sometimes it wont? In my crontab command, I'm using MAILTO="email@email.com" and it works properly most of the time, but sometimes it doesn't send an email even when the script is executed correctly. Do you know why this might happen?

Comment: That probably has something to do with your email configuration. I'm not sure exactly what cron does to send email, and a quick glance at the man pages is not illuminating.