# How to save python virtual env pip freeze from cron each time the machine starts

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron, virtualenv

I am trying to save the output of `pip freeze` of some of my python virtual enviroments each time my machine starts. So I initially have built the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/myuser/pathtovenv/bin/pip freeze > /somepath/requirements_`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'`.txt
```

It works fine when I execute it in the terminal.

So I added to the crontab:

```
@reboot cd /path_where_sh_is; ./freeze_venv.sh
```

and a few other variations:

```
@reboot /path_where_sh_is/freeze_venv.sh
```

without success.
Why is that? How should I write the crontab line to make it work?

Comment: Your script doesn't contain any relative paths. Have you tried `/path_where_sh_is/freeze_venv.sh` instead of using `cd`?

Comment: @chepner Yes, that was the first option that I tried. Same result

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-executing-a-python-script

Comment: You haven't said what the result is yet. "without success" could mean any number of things.

Comment: @chepner In this case "without success" means that the expected requirements txt file is not created.