# Does crontab take command line arguments?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have written a code which moves `.trc` files from source directive to backup directive. Now I have taken time (how much time older), source path and backup path as command line arguments for this file. Now when I invoke the script from `sh`, it works fine. But in crontab it is not working, which left me wondering if crontab allows passing command line arguments or not. My `sh` command is :

```
sh trace_bkp.sh 2 /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix /home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp
```

where `2` defines 2 minutes older files, next one is soruce path and the last one is target path. I set the same in crontab as:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix/trace_bkp.sh 2 /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix /home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp
```

Comment: If you run this command: `sh /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix/trace_bkp.sh 2 /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix /home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp` while you are in `/root` as user `root` does it work?

Comment: also in which crontab to you write this? Your own (user) crontab or the system wide (root) crontab?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs, There is no newline. Thanks for the edit. How do I check whose crontab is this? I only use `crontab -e` and write my code in it.

Comment: When you call `crontab -e` as which user do you do it? As user or as root?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs, As user!! Also, my other crons work this way. Also after hard-coding the values, cron ran the script fine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, crotab lines can get arguments as the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205) says so.

Most likely something goes wrong while calling that command that resides in the change of environment from your console to the not-a-console cron environment.

Usually its best to add [logging functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/cron-job-log-how-to-log) to your cron line to get the output of whats happening.

```
*/5 * * * * sh /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix/trace_bkp.sh 2 /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix /home/adhikarisubir/test_bkp >> /home/adhikarisubir/test/basic_unix/cron.log 2>&1
```

Then read that log and you will see how it goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I found the error. It is the mising `/` in front of `home` while passing argument in crontab.