# Running cron jobs on aws elastic beanstalk - django

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having trouble getting my cron jobs to execute.

Setup:

Django - 1.9

Elastic beanstalk - 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.3 running Python 3.4

I've tried doing this a couple of ways so far:

1. Using a cron.yaml file:
   Didn't touch anything else - just added a cron.yaml file to my project root folder

   ```
   version: 1
   cron:
     - name: "test"
   url: "http://website.com/workers/test"
   schedule: "*/10 * * * *"
   ```
2. Using a container command and a separate cron.txt file:

Added this line in my .ebextensions/development.config file

```
05_some_cron:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/crontab.txt > /etc/cron.d/crontab && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/crontab"
    leader_only: true
```

and in .ebextensions/crontab.txt

```
*/10 * * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python mysite/manage.py test
```

The app deploys successfully in both cases.

1. Manually (in a browser) going to http://website.com/workers/test has
   the intended outcome (in the first case).
2. Adding `source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python mysite/manage.py test` as a management command runs the correct script once on deploying.

The logs do not show any GETS on that url.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some step of the process or some setup step on EBS?

Also what is the best ways to run cron jobs for django applications hosted on EBS? - django apps can run management commands either from the command line as in attempt 2 or by extending a GET or POST url as in attempt 1.

Comment: Are you seeing any extra information in your cron logs?

Comment: @PeterBrittain Nope - the logs are the same as a normal deployment without the cron.yaml file

Comment: And have you tried looking at what happens when your commands are running - as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/cron-job-log-how-to-log?

Comment: cron.yaml in ElasticBeanstalk only sends POST requests to the designated endpoint.

Comment: Have you check out this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719447/3518108 ?

Comment: You may be having issues with your I AM roles / security groups. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59520061/5403449

Answer (score 5):

**2018 Update** using **Django 2.0.6** + AWS ElasticBeanstalk + Cronjob

I found I needed to export the AWS environment variables using source /opt/python/current/env to prevent manage.py from throwing the error "The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty".

This is because I had placed my Django Secret key in the os.environ for beanstalk which it seems is not accessible by shell/cron by default.

See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=108465

My final cron job .txt script was as follows. (process_emails is my own **django management function**, myjob.log is where the output of the function call is logged).

```
*/15 * * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && cd /opt/python/current/app/ && source /opt/python/current/env && python manage.py process_emails >> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Using Django 2.1.1 as of today (2020 April) with AWS ElasticBeanstalk, I can confirm that this is still a valid solution!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me in **Django 1.10.6** + **AWS ElasticBeanstalk** + **Cronjob**

`* * * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && cd /opt/python/current/app/ && python manage.py do_your_thing > $HOME/cron-sqs.log 2>&1`

**do_your_thing** is a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)