# Can't configure cron to execute php files

Tags: php, apache, cron

I try to make cron execute a php file.
I opened crontab, wrote:

```
07 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/folder/cron.php
```

The php file should send an email.

But cron doesn't work. The php script works itself.

Ideas?

Comment: Does it run when you call it manually on the command line?

Comment: Yes, It runs...

Comment: You can store the results of the CRON run. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/cron-job-log-how-to-log

Comment: sending mail is an unreliable test.

Comment: The scipt works when I execute it. I suppose, the cron doesn't work itself

Comment: crontab -l gives 'No crontab for root'

Comment: then how do you install this crontab? it does not seem to exist (at least for root, perhaps another user)

Comment: Running php from command line says 'Could open input file'