# Crontab output is not getting captured to log file

Tags: bash, unix, cron

Below is my crontab entry :

```
* 4 * * * find /path/to/apache/logs -name "apache_*" -type f -mtime +20 -exec rm -f {} \; > /home/user/Deleted-`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1
```

it is finding the files older than 20 days and removes those without any issue but I'm not able to capture those deleted files' name on the log file.

I have even used the above command in a bash script and tried as below but the same issue.

```
* 4 * * * /path/to/log_rotate.sh > /home/user/Deleted-`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any suggestion please.Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Empty log file? Why do you expect `rm -f` to output anything at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to log cron jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811738/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-v` option to the `rm` command so that it prints which files it's deleted.

`` * 4 * * * find /path/to/apache/logs -name "apache_*" -type f -mtime +20 -exec rm -fv {} \; > /home/user/Deleted-`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.log 2>&1 ``