# How to move content of folder to unique folders every three hours in linux platform?

Tags: linux, unique, move

Whenvever my computer starts up I want to move contents of a folder to a unique folders.

For Example, Folder "A" has some Pictures then in the start up I want to MOVE the contents to a new folder "B". Again after 3 Hours I want to Move the contents from Folder "A" to newly Created Folder "C". Every Three hours I want a new folder to made for keeping the Content. Can any one help?

Comment: See the crontab manpage.

Comment: Yes, cron is the way to go

Comment: Sounds like a job for logrotate or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a script that creates backup accordingly to specified parameters. To add it to your system do following steps:

1. You could save as something like `folder_backup` (don't forget to make script executable by performing `$ chmod +x folder_backup`).
2. *(OPTIONAL step)* After that you could copy it to `/usr/local/bin` if you want your script to be executable as command from any directory (`sudo cp folder_backup /usr/local/bin`).

Now you are ready to execute script with either typing `$ ./folder_backup` or `$ folder_backup` (if you copied / moved it to `/usr/local/bin` or other `bin` directory).

*Usage:* `folder_backup FOLDER_NAME [BACKUP_FOLDER_NAME]`
(backup folder name is optional, if you won't specify it will save backup at `FOLDER_NAME_Year-Month-Day_Hour:Minutes`.

Now that you have everything needed you just have to execute script in while or for loop for example: `while true; do sleep TIME_IN_SECONDS; folder_backup FOLDER_NAME; done`. This will create backup folders with timestamps if specified folder is not empty. For your specific case `TIME_IN_SECONDS` should be `10800`, so command would look like `while true; do sleep 10800; folder_backup A; done` However you could write your own algorithm of backup folder naming and add it as second variable after name `A`. Also you should note that this won't run in background, if you want it to run in background simply add `&` to end of `while` loop (after `done`).

Hope this is what you seek!!!

```sh
#!/bin/bash

create_backup () {
    # Check if 2 arguments are given to function.
    if [ -z ${3+x} ]; then
        # Check if folder from which we will make backup exists.
        if [ -d ${1} ]; then
            echo "Creating backup in ${2} of folder ${1}..."
            mkdir -p ${2}
            mv ${1}/* ${2}/
            echo "Backup stored in ${2}."
        else
            echo "There is no folder in ${1}!"
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "You must specify folder and backup folder name!"
        exit 1
    fi
}

if [ -z ${2+x} ]; then
    # Only main folder specified
    main_folder=${1}
    date_stamp=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M`
    backup_folder=${main_folder}_"${date_stamp}
elif [ -z ${3+x} ]; then
    main_folder=${1}
    backup_folder=${2}
else
    echo "Specify folder path or folder name and backup folder path!"
    exit 1
fi

create_backup ${main_folder} ${backup_folder}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crontab can be used to achieve your need easily, more explanation for startup script is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247942/7706978)

Reboot or Startup activity:

```
#crontab -e
@reboot  /home/user/startup_script.sh
```

Regular interval:

```
#crontab -e
* */3 * * *  /home/user/interval_script.sh
```

Note: Design the scripts based on your need.

Comment: Thanks. How to know to  My crontab is working or not. I am not able to Track it.

Comment: One way is, You can redirect the script logs to a file manually using the redirect operator (> or >>). Otherwise, you can find the Cron job execution from the logs as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/cron-job-log-how-to-log) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207/where-are-cron-errors-logged).

Comment: @lifetree Are u able to setup?