# Crontab doesn't execute the .sh files

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian-buster

I recently discover crontab on my raspberry pi and I wanted to try it so I made different lignes for execute simples programs:
$

```html
0 21 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/Programmation/Batch/msg.sh

30 21 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/Programmation/Batch/msg2.sh

0 22 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/Programmation/Batch/msg3.sh

15 22 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/Programmation/Batch/msg4.sh

30 22 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/Programmation/Batch/msg5.sh

35 22 * * * /home/pi/Desktop/Programmation/Batch/msg6.sh
```

(I know: it's not batch but sh !!)
Here is the .sh program (there are all the sames):

```html
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Hello World !"
sleep 1000000000000000000
```

But that's doesn't work !!
I look on internet and I tried to change the TZ of crontab, I tried the command  timedatectl  to verify mi date settings :

```html
Local time: sam. 2020-10-10 18:23:37 CEST
           Universal time: sam. 2020-10-10 16:23:37 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: Europe/Paris (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

And That doesn't work... So please help me !! Thank you very much !!!

Comment: If you expect the `echo`s to print to your console, this won't happen.

Comment: What do you see in crontab logs? You can find them in `/var/log` directory.

Comment: The output is probably buffered and due to the eternal sleep, never visualised anywhere. You best validate that your programs work with `ps -aux`. If the large number is accepted by sleep, it will most likely still run

Comment: but @tkausl when I run  msg.sh that work !! The console appear and Isee "Hello World"

Comment: And @kvantour I doesn't understand ps -aux where do I put it ?

Comment: @IliaKondrashov I see many files but no one have cron or crontab on is name

Comment: @Nat'code here is a good explanation [how to enable and check cron logs on Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3741/where-do-cron-error-message-go), I think it will help you

Comment: Aaaah @IliaKondrashov thank you very much, I do that and I modifyed crontab to execute msg.sh at an another hour to test and... Can you help me for th log : ```Oct 11 17:15:01 raspberrypi CRON[4574]: (pi) CMD (/home/pi/Desktop/Programmation/Batch/msg.sh)``` but the cmd doesn't open !

Comment: Looks like your `msg.sh` was successully executed. Please note, that cron scripts do not have interactive shell, so you will not see anything in terminal. Good practice is to log both stdout and stderr somewhere - good example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/how-to-log-cron-jobs)

Comment: So @IliaKondrashov there are no way for me to see that the msg.sh as been executed (exept with a log file)? No notification, no terminal or page opened ?

Comment: That's right. Either you makr your script log something on it's own (or log output as I showcased earlier) or you can only verify the result, so check what script was supposed to make.

Comment: Ok thank you for our help !