# Cronjob Script not working for Graviton based EC2 instance with encryption enabled on EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, aws-graviton

I have one Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS EC2 Instance having Graviton2 arm64 Architecture. I have also enabled encryption on EBS volume.

I configured some cronjob bash script.

I was able to run those script manually by ./backup-script.sh command.

But when configured cron job below.

```
0 4 * * * /bin/sh /path/to/script/backup-script.sh
```

It is not able to execute.

I have other EC2 instances where cron job is running successfully but those are not graviton2 based instance neither EBS encryption enabled on them.

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to execute"? Have you checked the logs: [logging - How to log cron jobs? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/how-to-log-cron-jobs)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked logs `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`? It should have worked. Verified by running simple cron job on Grv2 instance Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Cronjob script is now working in graviton.

But any data from /var/ directory is not getting copy to s3.

It gives below error-

"The user-provided path /var/www/ does not exist."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).