# Ubuntu: oci: command not found

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, command-line-interface

I am using OCI CLI in ubuntu to automate a couple of things using crontab.
While using and oci command,ex:

```
oci --help
```

I get a list of oci commands. However, as soon as I put it into a bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
oci --help
```

and do the crontab with log, I get the error message:

```
   /home/ubuntu/lib/oracle-cli/bin/test: line 2: oci: command not found
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: When it opens a shell, cron will not inherit the environment variables (like `PATH`) that you use from the command prompt. You need to include the complete, explicit path to `oci` in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it opens a shell, cron will not inherit the environment variables (like `PATH`) that you use from the command prompt. You need to include the complete, explicit path to the `oci` command in your script. You can find this from your command prompt with the `which` command, as follows:

```
which oci
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by one of the following reasons:

- pip installed the package to a different virtual environment than
  your active one.
- You switched to a different active virtual environment after you
  installed the CLI.

To determine where the CLI is installed, run the

> which pip

and

> which oci

commands.

See this  [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log) ,it may help.
check this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/how-to-log-cron-jobs) too.